# Format Java Code in Netbeans / Eclipse, but save it differently

Tags: java, ide, formatting

I asked a related question before, but I guess the root of the question is.  Let's say I have 2 developers on the team and they both like to look at code in different formats.  One likes the braces to be on a new line and the other doesn't.

The approach I was using before is that anytime we run a build, the code is automatically formatted according to the Java/Sun standards using Jalopy; however, I would like the developers to be as happy as possible.  They can change the font size, font color, background color, etc.

If I am currently using the Jalopy Maven plugin to format code, can/should I write a hook to SVN that calls mvn jalopy:format on the project when it's checked in?  Is this reliable?

That solution doesn't work 100% because it requires the developer to manually format the source code to their liking every time they open a file that hasn't been formatted yet.  I was thinking an IDE plugin would be nice as it could automatically format the source to their liking and then save it as another.

What other options do I have to ensure the code is formatted nicely on checkin?

Thanks,

Walter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm.. if you use Eclipse you can do the following:
1. configure the formating you like (Window/Preferences/Java/Code Style/Formatter)
2. configure clean up (Window/Preferences/Java/Code Style/Clean Up), under edit check "Format source code"
3. if a developer has a project he can right click on it and source/clean up

The complete project will be then cleaned with the rules you defined there. So therefore after this he would have his own formatting.

Comment: i just saw that you can do this even easier without cleanup just define your own code format style and do right click on the project and "Format" (at least with eclipse 3.5)

Comment: That is true, I'd like to keep it automatic if possible otherwise, it's still something they have to actively do and that defeats the whole purpose.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you are wasting your resources with this. Code format is (between certain limits) a question of taste; howewer, people working as a team should be able to agree on using a common coding style.

Once someone has worked on a couple of projects, (s)he knows from experience that one's brain can learn a new code format in a matter of days; after that, it is as easy to interpret as the earlier favourite. Thus, one stops having one "favourite" code format. So I must note that sticking to a specific code format is a beginner's malady; your team would be better trying to get over it to focus on the development itself.

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely right, it is trivial.  In this day and age, we have the power to configure/optimize any setting we like.  Each developer is responsible for his/her machine/environment.  I provide images to get started from, but they can use an etch-a-sketch if they want and can check-in/out code with it.